# Tachometer vs. Tachogenerator

Tags: tachometer

Could you explain to me the differences between a tachometer and a tachogenerator? For example, is a tachometer just a  tachogenerator attached to a dial to display RPM rather than voltage or are they two completely different devices?

Thank you.

Comment: the key words are generator and meter. so it takes both for a working system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tachometer is an instrument to display RPM of some rotating shaft.

A tachometer consists of tachogenerator (a sensor on the rotating shaft), and an electronic circuit that displays the sensed input.

The tachogenerator might generate either analog voltage proportional to RPM ("analog tachos"), or square pulses with period proportional to RPM. Or it can be a unit that already sends its output in some digital serial format.

The display could be an analog dial, or alphanumerical digital, or stepped motor-based, or some digital output to feed an on-board computer.

A tachogenerator can be a part of control loop, while tachometer is just a display for human readings.

Answer (score 0):

Tachogenerator is usually referred as permanent magnet DC brush generator. It has many slots and very fine brush collector. They usually output +/-10V at full RPM. Nowadays are being replaced with digital encoders, resolvers, ...but they were long time used as velocity feedback in servo drives.

Tachometer is a device that displays and/or registers the rotational speed.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the industry, but all tachogenerators that I deal with here are 50 or 100 V / 1000 rpm.  (yes, 2017, and STILL phasing out TG's.  /sigh)